# Fluent Validation Duplicate Errors in ModelState["Prop"]).Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, autofac, fluentvalidation

When I check my `ModelState["Email"].Errors`, I find the same validation error duplicated 3 times, and exactly 3 times for all my models, my models contain more than 3 properties.

I was wondering why the rules are getting executed three times.
I am using **MVC 5**, with **Autofac**. I can't find the mistake!
There are no errors, but I am concerned about performance if each property gets validated 3 times, some validations are complex and sometimes connect to the database.
Below is the code I use to register `Validators`, `Fluent Validation` and `Autofac`.

```cs
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("MyAssembly"))
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Validator"))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .InstancePerRequest();

builder.RegisterType<FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider>().As<ModelValidatorProvider>();
builder.RegisterType<AutofacValidatorFactory>().As<IValidatorFactory>().SingleInstance();

Container = builder.Build();// Build !

// FluentValidation wire up to MVC
var fluentValidationModelValidatorProvider = new fluentValidationModelValidatorProvider()
{
    AddImplicitRequiredValidator = false,
    ValidatorFactory = new AutofacValidatorFactory()
};

//fluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredValidator = false;

DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(fluentValidationModelValidatorProvider);

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(Container);
```

The Model looks like this:

```cs
public class ContactInfoDTO
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Email2 { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber2 { get; set; }
    public string EmergencyNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmergencyPersonName { get; set; }

    public ContactInfoDTO()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your model too?

Comment: Where do you define your fluent validation?

Comment: what do you mean by "define fluent validation"?
If you mean the first code Block, it executes once, in the Application_Start() in Global.asax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone, for their support.
Thanks to Mr. Jeremy Skinner, the owner of FluentValidation, has looked into it, the link to the solution below. 
it was my fault after all :)

https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/362

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should use Fluent validation:

```
using FluentValidation;

public class CustomerValidator: AbstractValidator<Customer> {
  public CustomerValidator() {
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Surname).NotEmpty();
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Forename).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please specify a first name");
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Discount).NotEqual(0).When(customer => customer.HasDiscount);
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Address).Length(20, 250);
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Postcode).Must(BeAValidPostcode).WithMessage("Please specify a valid postcode");
  }

  private bool BeAValidPostcode(string postcode) {
    // custom postcode validating logic goes here
  }
}

Customer customer = new Customer();
CustomerValidator validator = new CustomerValidator();
ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(customer);

bool validationSucceeded = results.IsValid;
IList<ValidationFailure> failures = results.Errors;
```

you should create a validator for you model so you can control what happens when you validate your object.

Comment: I already have a similar class, with a RuleFor each property, and no problems with that. I just dont want to paste it in, as it is quite fluffy. the few lines where u validate the model, is now done by the MVC pipeline, that utilizes autofac to inject the validators when MVC needs them. the Problem is within this part, MVC seems to execute the same rule 3 times!